# asp.net mvc convert Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> to Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, expression

I need to implement a custom helper that will return for a string that can have the value "1" or "0" a CheckBox instead of TextBox. So in custom helper I have:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomHelper<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
      ....
      Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> boolExpression = ??????????

      return helper.CheckBoxFor(boolExpression); 
    }
```

What should be assigned to 'boolExpression' variable?

Comment: Shouldn't the original expression be of type `Expression<Func<TModel, string>>` instead of `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`? This check for `"1"` or `"2"` only makes sense for a string property, doesn't it?

Comment: the problem is much more complex, I have tried to simplify it and reduce it to one row as few code as possible. The helper is for property of a list of values of the model..As I said, it's much more complex...

Comment: In that case, it might be a good idea to state your real problem. I have the feeling you oversimplified your code. A check on an arbitrary property type for two different strings simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

A ViewModel or a not-mapped property in a partial Model would be the way to go.

You won't be able to use `CheckBoxFor` on an inexisting property.

Imagine your String property with "0" or "1".

```
public string MyProperty{get;set;}


private bool myBooleanProperty_;
[NotMapped]
public bool MyBooleanProperty {
 get {
   myBooleanProperty_ = MyProperty == "1";
   return myBooleanProperty_;
}
set {
   myBooleanProperty_ = value;
}
```

Then you can use

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBooleanProperty)
```

When you post values in a form, you'll have of course to set a value to `MyProperty`, depending on value of `MyBooleanProperty`.